# Adding column headers to XAML grid

Tags: xaml

I need to put column headers (labels) over the 2nd and 3rd columns.  These headers do not repeat for the values that are bound and should only be in row 0.  I can add the labels but they get repeated for every row in the grid.  I only need them at the top.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
<ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Column1, StringFormat=c2}" md:HintAssist.Hint="{Binding Payment.Column1}"  client:SelectTextOnFocus.Active="True" Margin="8" MinWidth="150" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Height="45" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Column2, StringFormat=c2}" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" Height="45" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Column3, StringFormat=c2}" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add two RowDefinition, size them "Auto" and "*".
- Then add Grid.Row = "0" and the corresponding Grid.Column to each of the headers.
- move all stackpanel to the next row by Adding Grid.Row="1" to each stackpanel.